# org-mode before load hook

Tags: org-mode

Is there an `org-mode` hook that fires before `org` loads?

I have some font-lock settings that require me to run `org-reload` for theme to stick. But I thought it might be cleaner if I could wrap these settings in a hook that fires before `org` loads, to begin with?

Comment: Does it not work when you just set those settings in your init files? Org should not yet be loaded when the init file runs. Org should be auto loaded when you open an org file ... at least when you use the version from elpa/melpa.

Comment: Hm. If org-mode is not loaded yet, why would I need to "reload" org-mode to get my code to stick? Yes, the settings work. But I thought if there was a hook, it might make things a little cleaner and faster loading.

Comment: Note, if you want specific help the information in your question is not sufficient. Which font lock settings fail in org-mode? How do you recognize it? What is your emacs version, what is your org version. Construct a minimal recipe for re-construction of the problem starting with `emacs -Q`! It might be that something in your init file requires org-mode. (Some people even write [their full initialization in org-mode](http://mescal.imag.fr/membres/arnaud.legrand/misc/init.php).) The font lock settings then should go to the front of that.

Comment: I just want to know whether there is a hook available, that fires before org-mode loads -- something like org-will-load-hook -- or if not, how I could implement this?